# Find out which item from a list is matched in a python pandas row

Tags: python, pandas, string, match

I have a dataframe (df_email) where one row corresponds to an incoming email. Some of the emails cannot be identified by sender email adress, so I try to identify it by looking for names in the email content. I have a list of names, and I can find out if I have any items from my list of names matching like this:

```
Names = ['Anders','Camilla','Herman','Alma','Solveig']

df_match = df_email.loc[df_email.Email_body.str.contains('|'.join(Names))
```

...but I don't know which of the names that are matching in each case. Basically what I need is to get out the name "Anders" if the email is: "Hi, can I order two books? Best regards Anders".

In reality my list of names contains more than 150000 names, and writing a for-loop that runs through all names is extremely ineffective (I stopped it after 30 minutes):

```
df_email.loc[:,"Customer_name"] = ''
for name in Names:
    df_email.Customer_name.loc[df_email.Email_body.str.contains(name)] = name
```

Is there a more effective way I can get which of the names are matched in the emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.findall` with the `'|'.join(Names)` regex you were using:

For example, if your dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Email_body": [
            "something somethine Camilla something",
            "hi Alma",
            "Anders and Solveig",
            "there is no name Here",
        ]
    }
)

                              Email_body
0  something somethine Camilla something
1                                hi Alma
2                     Anders and Solveig
3                  there is no name Here
```

You can do:

```
df["Customer_name"] = df.Email_body.str.findall("|".join(Names))

                              Email_body      Customer_name
0  something somethine Camilla something          [Camilla]
1                                hi Alma             [Alma]
2                     Anders and Solveig  [Anders, Solveig]
3                  there is no name Here                 []
```